# In react using axios how to handle request cancel on component unmount if the request is not done inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios

i am learning react requests and ran into an issue. As per my understanding, if a request is made inside a useEffect you can handle unmounting (not setting data if the component has unmounted) using abort controller and cleanup :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const getInformation = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axiosPrivate.get('/user/information', {
          signal: controller.signal,
        });
        setProfileInformation(response.data.user);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getInformation();

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, []);
```

What to do if the endpoint is called not inside useEffect but on button click? How to have the clean up function then? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need to because clicking a button itself is not a side-effect. If you want to use a single instance of axios, you can probably use `useRef` and save the instance inside the ref in the initial useEffect

Comment: But if i call an API on button click and that API takes a long time during which i navigate away from component and it unmounts. Don't i need to abort the api call?

Comment: No you don't have to, because when you unmount the component, the component gets destroyed